# git cherry-pick not applying all modifications of a commit

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have a commit with more than 14 files modified.

When I apply this commit in an other branch, the commit applied doesn't contain all these files but only 3 files.

The commands i'm using are:

```
git checkout mybranch
git cherry-pick COMMIT_HASH
```

Could you please tell me what should I add to be able to get all the modifications?

Comment: When cherry-pick doesn't apply a change that's part of a revision, in my experience it is because the change that is not being applied is already part of the branch that you are committing onto.

Comment: It could be that some of this work has already happened in your branch `mybranch`.  Or, Git could have gotten too smart for itself and "resolved" things by removing content.

Comment: can i avoid this and force it to apply all modifications